# How to fix "A value of type '(FirebaseUser) → Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type '(AuthCredential) → void'."?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up phone authentication on my app but I got stuck with this error "A value of type '(FirebaseUser) → Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type '(AuthCredential) → void'.". Any Idea on how to fix it? Thanks in advance for your help!

```
class _AuthScreenState extends State<AuthScreen> {
 String phoneNo;
 String smsCode;
 String verificationId;

Future<void> verifyPhone() async {

final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve =(String verId) {
  this.verificationId = verId;

};

final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent = (String verId, [int 
forceCodeResend]){
  this.verificationId = verId;
};

final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (FirebaseUser 
user) {
  print("Verificado");

};

final PhoneVerificationFailed verifiedFailed = (AuthException 
exception) {
  print("${exception.message}");

};

await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verifiedSuccess,
    verificationFailed: verifiedFailed,
    codeSent: smsCodeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve);
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `PhoneVerificationCompleted` used to receive `FirebaseUser` and return `void`, but this changed in some of the latest updates. Now it receives `AuthCredential`. Just change the type in the method that you assigned to the variable `verifiedSuccess`.

It should look like this:

```dart
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verifiedSuccess = (AuthCredential credential) {
  print("Verificado");
};
```

Comment: Valeu Hugo, realmente funcionou!!