# How to authenticate with phone number in flutter with firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm new to flutter,
and using firebase to authenticate with phone number but I m unable to authenticate.
I browsed for it but couldn't get any satisfying solution.

I implemented some code from the StackOverflow but there is occurring Exception 'Unhandled Exception: type '(FirebaseUser) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(AuthCredential) => void' in type cast' and couldn't catch the Exception.

```dart
signIn()async{
    AuthCredential credential= PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: verificationId,
      smsCode: smsCode
    );
    await firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((user){
       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
         print('signed in with phone number successful: user -> $user');
    }).catchError((e){
       print(e);
    });
  }
```

It will send you OTP to given phone number.

```
Future<void> verifyPhone()async{
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieval=(String verId){
      this.verificationId=verId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent=(String verId, [int forceCodeResend]){
      this.verificationId=verId;
      smsCodeDialog(context).then((value){
        print("Signed in");
      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (FirebaseUser user) {
     print('verified');
    } as PhoneVerificationCompleted;



    final PhoneVerificationFailed verfifailed=(AuthException exception){
      print("${exception.message}");
    };

    await firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
     phoneNumber: this.phoneNo,
     codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieval,
     codeSent: smsCodeSent,
     timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
     verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
     verificationFailed: verfifailed
    );
  }
```

pubspec.yaml

```dart
name: babilok
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  page_transition:
  firebase_auth:

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/login_wheel.png
    - assets/login_wheel1.png
    - assets/forward_arrow.png
    - assets/google_ads.png
    - assets/wheel.png
    - assets/red_cross.png
    - assets/welcome_logo.png
    - assets/money_bag.png
    - assets/user.png
    - assets/money_bag.png
    - assets/up_gift_wheel.png
    - assets/cross.png
    - assets/icons/facebook_logo1.png
    - assets/icons/twitter_logo1.png
    - assets/icons/instagram_logo1.png
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-adding-sign-in-with-google-and-phone-authentication-to-your-app-69f681518f9b)

Comment: I updated my code and got an exception `Unhandled Exception: type '(FirebaseUser) => Null' is not a subtype of type '(AuthCredential) => void' in type cast`

Comment: Can please also add pubspec.yaml

Comment: okay, I added pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have found the solution from stackOverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56434203/how-to-fix-a-value-of-type-firebaseuser-%E2%86%92-null-cant-be-assigned-to-a-varia),

```
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted = (AuthCredential credential) {
   print('verified');
  };
```