# Flutter Firebase Phone Authentication not working

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Phone authentication getting failed with the following exception :

PlatformException(ERROR_SESSION_EXPIRED, The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again., null)

But it works if I use a different phone number other than that on my phone. I've added both SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprints from the play store to firebase and also replaced the google-services.json.

Here's my code :

```
 void _verifyPhoneNumber() async {
    setState(() {
       isVerified=true; 
      });
    setState(() {
      _message = '';
    });
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
      _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
      setState(() {
        _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';

      });
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
        _message =
            'Phone number verification failed';

    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      _verificationId = verificationId;

    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+91'+_phoneNumberController.text,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
  }

  // Example code of how to sign in with phone.
  void _signInWithPhoneNumber() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading=true;
    });
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _smsController.text,
    );
    try{
      firebaseUser =
        (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
    assert(firebaseUser.uid == currentUser.uid);
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
.....

      } else {

        _message = 'Sign in failed';
        showErrorDialog();
      }

    }catch (e){
      showErrorDialog();
    }
    setState(() {
      isLoading=false;
    });
  }
```

Comment: [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57373903/how-to-authenticate-with-phone-number-in-flutter-with-firebase/57393847#57393847) may be You'll get your solution.

Answer (score 2):

not sure of your problem but it says : **ERROR_SESSION_EXPIRED, The sms code has expired** and in `_auth.verifyPhoneNumber()` your **Timeout duration** is quite low. try **60 Seconds**.

```
await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+91${_phoneNumberController.text}',
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
```

and if this didn't help give a look at the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth) .

Comment: Weird part is that the error occurs only if the sim is in same device

Comment: Sorry to hear that, you can check this [post](https://medium.com/@fayaz07/firebase-phone-auth-with-flutter-db7e934ef46f)

Comment: Not true because the doc says:
`If you specified a positive value less than 30 seconds, library will default to 30 seconds.`

Comment: The timeout is not for SMS validity. Please read the documentation. It's auto verify timeout. Doc: "The maximum amount of time you are willing to wait for SMS auto-retrieval to be completed by the library. Maximum allowed value is 2 minutes"

Answer (score 1):

Its late ,but for others who are struggling, it's all is about the incomplete explanation of docs for login and signup.

**comment the code  of signin in _verifyPhoneNumber() function, add async to the function and make AuthCredential to PhoneAuthCredential**

```
  final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
    (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async{
 // comment the below code for _auth.signIn and add async

 // _auth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
  setState(() {
    _message = 'Received phone auth credential: $phoneAuthCredential';

  });
```

Actually the _verifyPhoneNumber() checks the number in database ,so you can redirect user direct to Home Screen from this function.As the signIn runs two times ,one here and one in signinwithPhone Number() , so it gives timeout error.

Comment: This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Right,although timeout property is 60s.
But after receiving the verification code and pasting the code immediately, `ERROR_SESSION_EXPIRED` like you.
note: only on Android,just receive on a few phone number.

Answer (score 0):

If you missed  `timeout: Duration(seconds: 60)` in your

```
_auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: '+91${_phoneNumberController.text}',
        timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);
```

This issue may happen